# Convergence into law of a random series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Theorem: Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real random variables independent on $(\Omega; F; P)$. The following assertions are equivalent.

1. $\sum X_n$ converges to the law.
2. $\sum X_n$ converges in probability.
3. $\sum X_n$ converges almost surely.

Where can I find the proof of this theorem?
Thank you.

Comment: Those assertions are not equivalent. $3$ implies $2$ but $2$ does not implies $3$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following books:   
 
J. Neveu, *Mathematical Foundations of the Calculus of Probability*, Holden-Day, Inc. 1965. p.157, Corollary IV.7.1.   
S. I. Resnick, *A Probability Path*, Birkhäuser Boston, 2005. p.211, Th 7.3.2.